# Unity - How to rotate game screen?(Not mobile phone rotation)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity 2020.1.17f.

To do align correction between VR lens and Display, I want to control size of screen, offset of screen, and rotation of screen(screen means area of display where actual game scene is appeared, my game has letter box in 4 ways).

I could control size and offset by changing values of Viewport Rect, but I cannot find a way to control rotation of screen. (Like Cv2.GetRotationMatrix2D() of openCV in C#)

You can say "why don't you rotate your camera?", but rotating camera is not what I want. As you know, in VR, Game screen is distorted in several shapes to optimize to their lens shape. Thus, even I rotate camera, it is not helpful for mis-align correction.

In Google, there are many answers, but only related with rotation of mobile phone, not controlling rotation in arbitrary angle(that what i really want).

How can control of rotation of game screen?

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to `Edit/PlayerSettings/Player`

And open the section called **resolution and presentation**

[image]

as you see there is a section called **default orientation** and here you can set the orientation of the build just opened.

Down there is also a section called **Allowed orientations for auto rotations** where you can set the other rotations allowed. In my case, everything is allowed, but you can just set the 2 landscapes or the 2 portraits depending on your game and your canvas and camera orientation

Comment: I'm sorry. My words made you confused. 
What I look for is rotating game display in arbitrary angle(Like Cv2.GetRotationMatrix2D() in OpenCV CSharp). 
Thanks for your answer, but it was not I want.